# Google Analytics New vs Returning visitors for a particular url

Tags: google, google-analytics

I am looking to query Google Analytics to get New vs Returning visitors for a particular url. Can someone help me to understand how to generate these results?

Answer (score 1):

The New vs Returning report in Google Analytics is found under Audience > Behavior or you can use the search bar and type in "new vs" and it will be one of the first results that show.  From their you can go into more advanced data.

There is a dropdown below the graph that says secondary dimension from there you can select further dimensions for breakdown such as which pages they visited, time on site, etc...  I belive that drop down box is what you are looking for.

[image: Secondary Dimension]